# Laravel - easy data entry form?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

Does Laravel provide a way to generate simple forms to make entries into database tables? I thought it did, but I can't seem to remember where I saw it or any documentation about it.

Comment: Probably thinking of Jeffrey Ways generators package?

Comment: Try scaffold-interface to Generate your model,views,controller and migrations just in few clicks. its simple and useful https://github.com/amranidev/scaffold-interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this: 
https://github.com/jrenton/laravel-scaffold

This one was created for Laravel 4, not sure if anyone has updated it for Laravel 5

Answer (score 0):

Laravel 4 used a Form helpers package called HTML which provided a really simple way to generate forms, but this was removed from Laravel 5 to cut down on packages that came with it out of the box.

You can pull it in manually for Laravel 5 by:

- Requiring it - `composer require "illuminate/html":"5.0.*"`
- Adding it as a service provider in app.php (/config/app.php) - `'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider',`
- Adding the aliases to utilise it in app.php (/config/app.php) -

  ```
  'Form'=> 'Illuminate\Html\FormFacade', 
  'HTML'=> 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade',
  ```

You can then use this on your views like so:

```
{!! Form::open(array('url' => 'foo/bar')) !!}
    Form::text('foo')
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

This would generate a form for you on the page with correct HTML markup. E.g `Form::text('foo')` generates `<input name="foo" type="text">` on the page.

I'm not sure if this was what you were after, but if it was then this page [here](http://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.1/html) references all the ways you can use the package.

Comment: If I recall correctly, I didn't need to do any coding. I just access the table entry form via URL, possibly specifying the table name in the URL. It "automagically" created the form for me so I could do basic CRUD. It didn't look pretty, but it was perfect for what I needed. Not ringing any bells?

Comment: Not from me sorry, just did some searching and can't find any resource on it either. I know it requires coding, but using the form helpers definitely makes it easier. You could manually set it up yourself to do this through your controller by passing values through the URL, but again this would require coding from your side and isn't quite what you're after.

Comment: I might be going crazy, then. I don't use Laravel much, so I may be wrong.